# Camera software for Windows 7 and 8 (similar to Cheese)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, webcam, camera

Is there any good non-Java non-Metro counterpart for [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese) in Windows?

The Camera app in Windows 8 is a good alternative. However Metro apps do not work on my system.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what level of control you want, but if you're interested in something relatively immediate to use but that lets you take both still pictures and video with full control over the codec/compression options/resolution/etc. I might suggest [Daum PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/)

It's *primarily* a media player, but it has many other functions, including previewing the webcam and recording video / taking pictures from it. It lets you choose many options, but at the same time you can roll with the default ones and get good results if you're not a pro user.

Also, it's free, which is always a plus.

On the downside, it doesn't let you add "cheesy effects", but I guess you're not interested in them, since you cite the Win8 camera app as a good alternative and that doesn't have additional effects.

PS: You might be a bit lost the first time you open PotPlayer if you want to use it for video capture, so here's a quickstart tip:

- To open the webcam use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or do right click -> Open -> Open Webcam/Other Device.
- To take a still picture just prss <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, to record video <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- To change the picture/video capturing option use Right click -> Video -> Video Capture / Video Recording

Comment: My bad, to take a picture directly use CTRL-E (edited my answer)  
There's no default key to stat recording video directly, but you can assign one by going into "Preferences --> Genral --> Keyboard --> Add" and then select the "Video --> Video Recording --> Start Video Recording" entry and assigning the Hotkey you want.

Comment: Thanks. How can I target folder for  captured pictures?

Comment: @PHPst: Right click --> Preferences --> Location