# How can I record video from my camera?

Tags: windows, gratis, video, camera

I own a [CoolSNAP cf2 camera](http://www.photometrics.com/products/ccdcams/coolsnap_cf2.php) which I want to use for research, and I'm looking for software I can use to record video with it.

I've seen on the product site I can use NIS Elements, or Labview, but these are very expensive pieces of software. Does anyone know of any free alternatives?

Also I'm using Windows 8.1, and I have 0 budget.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. What OS (looking at the site I can guess, but you should make your question complete)? For the same reason: What is so special about this camera that you need special software for it? Since you are complaining about price, do you have *any* budget, or must it be free? Any other features it needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the free software [Micro-manager](https://www.micro-manager.org/) which allows for recording from my camera, it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Is this camera recognized as a webcam or similar standard device? Or does it have a special driver and proprietary interface?

If it reasonably standard, I like to use [PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/). It's a free media player that can also play and record video from webcams and other input devices, with full control over the video codec and quality settings.

Please refer to my answer [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18723/13681) for more details on how it works and to judge if it's a good solution for you.